# Shopee API request failed and give response "error_auth"

Tags: python, api

this is my first time asking in stackoverflow. I want to fetch data using Shopee API. I follow the documentation in Shopee but it always return "error_auth". How can I fix this ? Here is the code below :

```
import hmac
import time
import requests
import hashlib

timest = int(time.time())
host = "https://partner.shopeemobile.com"
path = "/api/v2/shop/auth_partner"
redirect_url = "http://localhost:3000"
partner_id = 
partner_key = ""

base_string = "%s%s%s"%(partner_id, path, timest)

signature = hmac.new(bytes( partner_key, 'utf-8'), msg = bytes(base_string , 'utf-8'), digestmod = hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

url = host + path + "?partner_id=%s&timestamp=%s&sign=%s&redirect=%s"%(partner_id, timest, signature, redirect_url)
```

And here is the respond :

```
{
  "request_id": "5e82043c27318f70007e4aca894f1365",
  "error": "error_auth"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't need a shopid aswell?

Comment: When I put the shop_id, it still return the same respond

Comment: I mean it seems like a credential issue...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Take the [tour] and read [ask]. Research is required by you. Please look in [Shopee API documentation under Authorization or Authentication](https://open.shopee.com/developer-guide/20) for a request-example] first. What is the purpose of `redirect_url` when sending the the authorization request ? Do you run a service on `localhost:3000` that can receive something ?

Answer (score -1):

I'm use this configuration for base_string and sign:

```
base_string = ("%s%s%s"%(partner_id, path, timest)).encode('utf_8')
sign = hmac.new(partner_key, base_string, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Isn't the `str.encode('utf-8')` here equivalent to `msg = bytes(base_string , 'utf-8')` in the question's code ? Please explain a bit more, why you implemented it that way and why it solves the question.